# How to set customer specific pricelists which is common in B2B

Tags: virtocommerce

How to set customer specific pricelists which is common in B2B.
Pricelists per customer or organisation.
If this not exist out of the box, should i tag pricelists witch dynamic properties or add a custom condition, what is tag (TagsContainsCondition).
It dosnt seems to be possible to add own conditions for pricelist assignments!?

I guess this is the best method to override if you dont want to send to many pricelists to the client:

PricingServiceImpl.EvaluatePriceLists

Answer (score 0):

This is already possible out of the box. Simply go to price list assignments and then add a new condition: "Tags contains". In the frontend, you'll need to populate the tags passed to the pricing engine with whatever values you'd like, for instance it can be customerid, or organization name.

You can also extend and add your own conditions as described here: http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Composing+dynamic+conditions.